# Pure CSS3 icon without nested SPANs

Tags: html, css, icons

I'm creating pure CSS3 icons. The way I'm doing it now requires me to have multiple levels of nested SPANs in some cases.

The parent SPAN is used in most cases for the icon's background. Then I use :before and :after to insert more elements.
If I need more than two additional elements, I need to put more SPANs into the parent, which I can also fill up and insert with :before and :after.

This method works nicely, but it would be nice if I could eliminate HTML that looks like this:

```
<span class="btn"><span></span><span></span></span>
```

So I'm wondering if there's a better way?
Some examples below.

```css
.softwareBtn {
  position: relative;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#908dbe, #5e5c84, #5e5c84, #908dbe);
  display: block;
}
.softwareBtn:before,
.softwareBtn span:nth-child(1):before,
.softwareBtn span:nth-child(1):after,
.softwareBtn span:nth-child(2):before,
.softwareBtn span:nth-child(2):after,
.softwareBtn span:nth-child(3):before,
.softwareBtn span:nth-child(3):after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
.softwareBtn:before {
  top: 7px;
  right: 7px;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.softwareBtn span:nth-child(1):before,
.softwareBtn span:nth-child(2):before,
.softwareBtn span:nth-child(2):after {
  top: 4px;
  right: 13px;
  width: 3px;
  height: 15px;
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 3px 0 3px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.softwareBtn span:nth-child(1):after {
  top: 13px;
  right: 4px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 3px;
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 3px 0 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.softwareBtn span:nth-child(2):before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.softwareBtn span:nth-child(2):after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.softwareBtn span:nth-child(3):before {
  bottom: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, #999, black, #999);
}
.softwareBtn span:nth-child(3):after {
  bottom: 9px;
  left: 9px;
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.emailBtn {
  position: relative;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#908dbe, #5e5c84, #5e5c84, #908dbe);
  display: block;
}
.emailBtn:before,
.emailBtn:after,
.emailBtn span:before,
.emailBtn span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
.emailBtn:before {
  top: 7px;
  left: 3px;
  width: 26px;
  height: 18px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, #d6f1e9, #fff);
}
.emailBtn:after {
  top: -1px;
  left: 7px;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px 0 1px 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px 0 1px 3px;
  border-radius: 1px 0 1px 3px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.emailBtn span:before,
.emailBtn span:after {
  top: 20px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px;
  border-radius: 1px;
}
.emailBtn span:before {
  left: 2px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.emailBtn span:after {
  right: 2px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<span class="softwareBtn"><span></span><span></span><span></span></span>
<br />
<span class="emailBtn"><span></span></span>
```

Comment: That's such a complex icon, I don't think if there's a better way than your way. Looks nice BTW.

Comment: May be try this link:-https://codepen.io/rgg/pen/ZGKyrB

Comment: @PraveenKumar : Thank you :)

Comment: @Raziasultana : thanks for the link. Those look nice, but use essentially the same method I do as far as I can tell. Those icons just happen to not need any additional spans.

BTW - I noticed I neglected to use the actual span contents for the softwarebutton, so potentially one of them could be eliminated.

Comment: I believe creating DOM nodes for styling is a poor practice. To me, your challenge sounds perfectly suitable for SVG, which can then be applied to the single, semantically correct `button` element in various ways (background-image, ::before/after content or even inline).

Comment: @elektronik Thanks for your answer. I have started making SVGs now. A bit of a learning curve though.
Is there by any chance to convert HTML/CSS to SVG?

Comment: @bur, I'm not familiar with such tools. Let me know if you find anything!

Comment: @elektronik doesn't seem to be anything, using SVG-Edit to recreate my icons :)